# Incremental deployment, why is that?

Tags: continuous-deployment

So far, I've encountered different scenarios of deployment, at least three types.

1. Full Build, Full Deploy. Like most of Java, .Net applications, have a Jenkins job builds the whole application and deploy the whole application.
2. No Build, Incremental Deploy. Like Mainframe, Informatica, Vitria, even database, these types of applications, they only deploy files got changed.
3. Full Build, Incremental Deploy. e.g. a not well structured Java application. The build generate total 7 jars, but only one of them is actually changed, and they want to deploy only this jar. Same for .net applications.

After google, I believe the 3rd case is not following best practice and should be resolved at the application architecture level. [How to structure, partition, and build large MVC application for deployment in small incremental pieces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917077/how-to-structure-partition-and-build-large-mvc-application-for-deployment-in-s)

The 1st case, is simple. We take everything from the source control system, build it and deploy it.

The tricky one is the 2nd. I have to generate a list of changed file in this build and deploy them. Any good experience on how to handle this well?

Answer (score 0):

For incremental deployment, I use rsync. It's a program for synchronizing files, directories, permissions, etc. By default, it performs the task of figuring out which files have changed. When you have gigs of data and fifty thousand of files, re-deploying is fast and can be automated.

Comment: I tried using rsync but the issue is that files are getting copied even if they are not getting update.